# mellanox official website test program gpu_direct_rdma_access occurred Couldn't register GPU MR

Tags: gpu, rdma

I used the official website library of gpu direct rdma, gpu_direct_rdma_access. When I was testing the program, the code reported an error, and the Debug information was as shown in the figure below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf8FT.png)

Finally, the reason for finding the error is that the ibv_reg_mr registered memory in line 1170 of gpu_direct_rdma_access.c returns nullptr. What is the reason for this.
The address of the code is  https://github.com/Mellanox/gpu_direct_rdma_access
The GPU I use is NVIDIA RTX TITAN and HCA is Connect-X5

Comment: Do you have the `nv_peer_mem` module loaded?

Comment: yes,i use the commmand service nv_peer_mem status system to output nv_peer_mem is loaded

Comment: Perhaps GPUDirect isn't supported on this GPU. https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/titan-rtx-rdma-gpu-direct-possible/160006

Comment: yeah,i think so.i will choose Tesla GPU to test this program.thank you for your answer